# What is stored in %Windir%\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup?

Tags: windows, files, wmi, trace

I occasionally notice in Resource Monitor hard disk activity related to ETL files in the folder C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup.

**Which process/service creates these ETL files and what is their purpose?**

Resource Monitor shows "System" as the process which is correct since ETW traces (that is what ETL files are) are created by the kernel. But I am interested in the process that causes the traces to be created.

This happens on Windows 7, by the way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer myself after digging around some more.

The directory `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup` stores ETW trace files (extension .etl) for real time event trace sessions. Looking into the RtBackup directory is a little difficult because by default only System has permissions, but my application [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/) can display the contents anyway. When putting the directory's content next to the list of running event trace sessions, one immediately notices the similarities:

[image]

[image]

Not every event trace session generates a file in the directory RtBackup. As the directory's name implies, it stores backups for **real time** trace sessions. Comparing the list of files in RtBackup to each trace session's properties confirms this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was hoping this would be an easy answer, but I guess I would have to force a read/write of the file or know when it is happening.  In any event, this is what I tried hoping for a quick one-off.  You will need the [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utility from SysInternals.

```
\path\to\handle.exe | find /i "etl"
```

Good luck and happy hunting.

Comment: The ETL file is accessed by the kernel. That much I see in Resource Monitor. My question is who makes the kernel create the file in the first place?

Comment: Ok. Possible technique to determine you answer. They are just backup files, so move (*do not delete*) to a separate location. Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Create a filter on the file names, and look at the Kernel API calls and until they are created. Apparently you might need to get [the debug symbols involved](http://natesstuff.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!927B27E35FC3B535!426.entry). I know this is not solid advice, but this is the best way I can think of. Sorry if it does not help too much.